# Comunicação de DLL's com Java

Tags: java, dll

Sou leigo no assunto de como se comunicar com DLL's utilizando a plataforma do JAVA. Gostaria de saber por onde começar a estudar, se existe algum framework? Ouvi falar de JNI mas não sei se é o certo usar.

Qualquer documentação, link, framework, api e etc são bem vindos.

Comment: O caminho é o JNI sim, mas infelizmente conheço pouco disso. Há também o JNA. Fica com o meu +1 porque também tenho interesse nisso.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo usando JNI e JNA. http://blog.caelum.com.br/escrevendo-metodos-nativos-em-java-com-jni-e-jna/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme comentário do [Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171279/comunica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dlls-com-java), duas alternativas comuns para consumir código nativo são o [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (mecanismo padrão do Java) e [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (uma biblioteca bastante popular para consumir bibliotecas C).

Em uma simplificação grosseira podemos dizer que a principal diferença entre as duas é que com JNI a maior parte do "mapeamento" é feito do lado da aplicação C/C++. Já com JNA o mapeamento é feito do lado do Java.

JNA é uma abstração sobre o JNI conveniente para trabalhar com C; mapear código C++ acaba dando bastante trabalho e nem sempre é possível.

### JNI

Ao usar JNI você tem um processo de desenvolvimento que geralmente consiste em:

1. Criar uma classe com métodos marcados como nativos (`native`) no Java.
2. Compilar a classe (e.g., `javac`)
3. Criar *headers* e *stubs* C/C++ para a classe em questão (usando [`javah`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html))
4. Escrever a implementação de "ponte" em C/C++. por exemplo, delegando chamadas para seu *dll* original
5. Criar uma biblioteca compartilhada com o código que você escreveu (e.g., `libPonte.dll`)
6. Carregar a biblioteca nativa (e.g., usando [`System.loadLibrary`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-))

Seguem alguns links sobre JNI:

1. [IBM developerWorks - Java programming with JNI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html)
2. [Oracle Blogs | MoonOcean - A simple example of JNI](https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni)
3. [Oracle - Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

### JNA

Já a integração usando JNA geralmente começa dos *headers* originais da biblioteca, seguindo o seguinte processo:

1. Identificar funções nativas que você deseja chamar.
2. Incluir o arquivo `jna.jar` no *classpath* da aplicação
3. Declarar uma interface de mapeamento do lado do Java (herdando de [`Library`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Library.html)) ou uma classe com métodos `native` e [mapeamento direto](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/DirectMapping.md). Os métodos dessa interface / classe devem ser uma contrapartida das funções C que você deseja chamar.
4. Mapear estruturas, ponteiros de função e outras particularidades. *Structs* em C são mapeadas para classes Java que herdam de [`Structure`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Structure.html). Ponteiros de função em C são mapeados para classes Java que herdam de [`Callback`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Callback.html).

   - Opcionalmente os passos 3 e 4 podem ser automatizados. Ferramentas como o [JNAerator](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator) são capazes de gerar o mapeamento a patir do *dll* e dos *headers* da biblioteca.
5. Carregar a biblioteca nativa com os métodos [`loadLibrary`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) ou [`register`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#register-java.lang.String-)

Seguem alguns links sobre JNA:

1. [Calling C code from Java using JNA](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna)
2. [Getting Started with JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)
3. [JNA API Documentation](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html)

---

É necessário mencionar que existem outras bibliotecas com o mesmo propósito do JNA; a escolha da biblioteca costuma envolver um *trade-off* entre simplicidade e controle. Menção honrosa para o [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) capaz de gerar interfaces para várias linguagens (incluindo Java / através de JNI) e [BridJ](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ) que se vende como uma alternativa ao JNA com suporte "real" à C++.

Mergulhando um pouco mais fundo você encontra o mundo legado de objetos distribuídos, incluindo bibliotecas como [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) (para [COM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)) e [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/) (para [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)) mas esse é um assunto para uma outra pergunta (específica sobre [IPC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos)).